# Where should I use atomic transactions in Django's save method?

Tags: python, django, transactions

Is this an appropriate use of atomic transactions? Why or why not?

```py
def save(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic:
            super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.image:
                img = Image.open(self.image.path)
                if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                    output_size = (300, 300)
                    img.thumbnail(output_size)
                    img.save(self.image.path)
    except (OSError, IOError):
        self.image = None
        with transaction.atomic:
            super(User, self).save(update_fields=['image'])
        raise PValidationError('Image can`t be saved')
```

Comment: I think you don't need the second atomic transaction because super().save() is already atomic (it happens or not, there nothing between).

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe you can use some thing like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        try:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            # do_other_things
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            transaction.commit()
        finally:
            transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

However the better is used some thing like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

please for more information check:[@transaction.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

good luck..!!

Comment: If I use atomic decorator, I can`t use try except inside this method because documenation says ```Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need any of the two atomic transactions actually. The best example when atomic transaction can be used is transfering the money from one account to another, for example:

```
def transfer_money(source_account, destination_account, quota):
    source_account.amount_of_money -= quota
    source_account.save()
    # K-BOOM
    destination_account.amount_of_money += quota
    destination_account.save()
```

What would happen if something went wrong in the `# K-BOOM` moment? One account would have less money and the second account would NOT have more as it should.

This is why we need the whole `transfer_money` function to be atomic:

```
@transaction.atomic
def transfer_money(source_account, destination_account, quota):
    source_account.amount_of_money -= quota
    source_account.save()
    # K-BOOM
    destination_account.amount_of_money += quota
    destination_account.save()
```